# Pushing address from database to Javascript Error: SyntaxError

Tags: php, regex, syntax

I have a database with data in including addresses. I am creating a google maps and when i am passing/pushing the data through to jQuery i get this message through firebug and my code breaks:

```
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

type.push(1st, Example );
```

Now i am assuming that this is as there 'special characters' in the address in the database. Is there a way to when the data is being pulled in to accept these special characters?

I am pushing my data out using this: `type.push(<?php echo $row['address']; ?>);`

and in the firebug in the script tab it is displayed as: `type.push(1st, Example);` so i know the data is coming through just breaking as of the commas and numbers?

If anyone has any suggestions this would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to quote the string:

```
type.push("<?php echo $row['address']; ?>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `"` double quotes around it

```
type.push("<?php echo $row['address']; ?>");
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example:

```
type.push(1st, Example );
```

Javascript will treat each item as an variable. `1st` is not a valid variable name. 
Your javascript code should probably look like this:

```
type.push('1st, Example' );
```

You'd need to change your PHP to this:

```
type.push("<?php echo $row['address']; ?>");
```